# Removing bottom border on specific page

Tags: css, border

I have used CSS to give each of the page entries a bottom border that can be seen here. 
http://www.jobspark.ca/job-listings/

The problem is when you click on the page to open it at the very bottom of the page the border is visible. You have to look hard at the very bottom under the "print this job" to see it.

http://www.jobspark.ca/job-listings/2013/1/18/general-labourers.html

Looking to keep the border for the list but remove it when the page is opened. Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can find an independent class:

```
.single-journal-entry-wrapper .journal-entry-tag-post-body-line1{border:none 0;background:none;}
```

2.You add another class to the parent class:

```
.single-nobdbg .journal-entry-tag-post-body-line1{border:none 0;background:none;}
```

Comment: sorry about the confusion but I am talking about the border that is even below that. http://www.jobspark.ca/job-listings/2013/1/19/contract-grant-writer.html   Look at the bottom of the white page content and if you look at the rounded corners you will see it

Comment: The same method,but the class name is not the same. You try this:     `#modulePage19099460 .single-journal-entry-wrapper .journal-entry-wrapper{border-bottom:none 0;}`

Comment: #modulePage19099460 .single-journal-entry-wrapper .journal-entry-wrapper{border-bottom:none 0;} Thank you that worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following:

```
#modulePage19099460 .journal-entry-wrapper {
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this so that it is automatic. I don't really want to manually have to remove it each time I create a new page. Thanks for the quick response